# Microsoft Access field adds 1

Tags: ms-access, vba, field

I have a strange bug where my currency field adds $1 to every entry.  I have the values stored in a table, and use a lookup to get those values

```
ReducedLunch = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=2")
NormalLunch = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=1")
Milk = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=4")
NoLunch = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=5")
```

Then I have some VB code to write the appropriate value to the database field...

```
If (rs!TodaysLunch = "Lunch" And rs!FreeLunch = False And rs!ReducedLunch = False) Then
    DailyCost = NormalLunch
    rs.Edit
    rs!TodaysCost = DailyCost
    rs!Balance = rs!Balance - DailyCost
    rs.Update
End If
```

If I put a msgbox command before the Endif to show the DailyCost value it shows the correct value at this point, however when I actually write the data back to the table

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Lunch (StudentID, DateOfLunch, TypeOfLunch, Cost) SELECT [ID],[TodaysDate],[TodaysLunch],[TodaysCost] FROM Students"
```

TodaysCost has added an extra dollar.  I've checked and double checked everything, but can't find where it's getting this mystery value from.  I tried setting DailyCost to zero (it's defined as currency), but it still writes back the value + 1.

Here is my complete code and the msgbox command near the end is at what point a 1 is added...

```
Dim DailyCost As Currency
Dim ReducedLunch, NormalLunch, Milk, NoLunch As Variant
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db As Database


DailyCost = 0

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Students")

    ReducedLunch = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=2")
    NormalLunch = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=1")
    Milk = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=4")
    NoLunch = DLookup("[Cost]", "LunchCost", "[ID]=5")


Do Until rs.EOF = True
    'Check for free or reduced and get price

    If (rs!TodaysLunch = "Lunch" And rs!FreeLunch = True) Then
        DailyCost = 0
        rs.Edit
        rs!TodaysCost = DailyCost
        rs!Balance = rs!Balance - DailyCost
        rs.Update
    End If

    If (rs!TodaysLunch = "Lunch" And rs!ReducedLunch = True) Then
        DailyCost = ReducedLunch
        rs.Edit
        rs!TodaysCost = DailyCost
        rs!Balance = rs!Balance - DailyCost
        rs.Update
    End If

    If (rs!TodaysLunch = "Lunch" And rs!FreeLunch = False And rs!ReducedLunch = False) Then
        DailyCost = NormalLunch
        rs.Edit
        rs!TodaysCost = DailyCost
        rs!Balance = rs!Balance - DailyCost
        rs.Update
    End If

    If (rs!TodaysLunch = "Milk") Then
        DailyCost = Milk
        rs.Edit
        rs!TodaysCost = DailyCost
        rs!Balance = rs!Balance - DailyCost
        rs.Update
    End If

    If (rs!TodaysLunch = "Lunch XtraMilk") Then
        ElseIf (rs!ReducedLunch = True) Then
         DailyCost = ReducedLunch + Milk * 2
        ElseIf (rs!FreeLunch = True) Then
            DailyCost = FreeLunch + Milk * 2
        ElseIf (rs!FreeLunch = False And rs!ReducedLunch = False) Then
            DailyCost = NormalLunch + Milk * 2
        rs.Edit
        rs!TodaysCost = DailyCost
        rs!Balance = rs!Balance - DailyCost
        rs.Update
    End If

    If (rs!TodaysLunch = "No Lunch") Then
        DailyCost = 0
        rs.Edit
        rs!TodaysCost = DailyCost
        rs!Balance = rs!Balance - DailyCost
        rs.Update
    End If

    'Set date to today
    rs.Edit
    rs!TodaysDate = Date
    MsgBox (rs!TodaysCost) 'Point where 1 is added
    rs.Update

   rs.MoveNext


Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Lunch (StudentID, DateOfLunch, TypeOfLunch, Cost) SELECT [ID],[TodaysDate],[TodaysLunch],[TodaysCost] FROM Students"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that TodaysCost is not Long Integer.

Comment: It's set as currency for the field.  I tried number with two decimals and it round up.  The sloppy/quick fix would be to subtract $1 from the final value, but I would prefer to find the bug.